# extract Username from inMemoryAuthentication() -WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I working on a school project with SpringBoot and after adding some security features (WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter) seen on the internet, I would like to know if there is a possibility to extract the username of the current logged in user because I need his id on other methods from controller 
in order to extract some information from the database.

My SecurityConfig class look like this

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*").access("hasRole('USER')")
                .antMatchers("/admin/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                // some more method calls
                .formLogin();
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)      throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("flaviu")
                .password("yes").roles("USER");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Bean
    public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to retrieve the currently authenticated principal is via a static call to the SecurityContextHolder:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String currentUserName = authentication.getName();
```

Get the User in a Controller:

```
@Controller
public class SecurityController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String currentUserName(Principal principal) {
        return principal.getName();
    }
}
```

we can also use the authentication token:

```
@Controller
public class SecurityController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String currentUserName(Authentication authentication) {
        return authentication.getName();
    }
}
```